# Add item to array based class property with generic method

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, typescript-generics

I have an example class, like:

```
export class FilterClass {
  searchText = '';
  someFilter: FilterType[] = [];
  otherFiler: OtherFilterType[] = [];

  setSearchText(searchText: string) {
    this.searchText = searchText;
  }
}
```

Now i'm trying to write a generic method to add new filters to filters arrays defined as this class properties. For now i have something like this:

```
  addFilter<T, K extends keyof FilterClass>(
    arrayName: K,
    filterToAdd: T
  ) {
    (this[arrayName] as unknown as T[]).push(filterToAdd);
  }
```

How can I get rid off casting it to unknown?

Comment: There's quite a bit going on here; without a [mre] defining `FilterType` and `OtherFilterType` I guess I can just make it up? And you seem to have too many generic type parameters, since `K` and `T` are not independent of each other.  Anyway, right now, [this](//tsplay.dev/mx3yXN) is the best I can do.  You need to tell the compiler that `arrayName` can only be certain keys, and the compiler doesn't automatically widen `this[arrayName]` to `FilterClass[K][number][]` so you need to do it yourself. Note that the widening is an annotation and not an assertion (you're calling this "casting").

Comment: If that meets your needs I can write up an answer explaining it.  If not, let me know what I'm missing.